# Osmosis: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). How not to use a password?

Tags: java, mysql, openstreetmap

I want to implement a task of Osmosis, I want to read `.osm.pbf` file and to write it to a db:

```
C:\osmosis-latest\bin>osmosis --read-pbf file="C:\sbox\maps\UA.osm.pbf" --write-apidb host="localhost" database="newb" user="root" dbType="mysql"
```

But I experience the following error:

```
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to establish a database connection.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My MySQL on Windows XP doesn't have a password. It is just blank. When I want to connect to a server I just provide a username, no any password:

```
C:\>mysql -u root -h localhost
```

But it seems that Osmosis force to use a password. But I don't want to set my MySQL to use a password. How may I change Osmosis settings not to use a password to connect to MySQL?

I tried to provide `password=""`, `password=null`. Both do not work, Osmosis doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user, set a password and specify user and password. Don't even think about a "problem" with no password.